# Remove Any kind of URL From string

Tags: php, regex

im looking for a `regex` to remove all kind of urls from my string.
assume this is the string that i want to clean it from urls;

`Hi , this is my website : http://my.website.com`

`Hi , this is my website : http://www.my.website.com`

`Hi , this is my website : http://www.website.com`

`Hi , this is my website : http://website.com`

`Hi , this is my website : https://website.com`

`Hi , this is my website : https://www.website.com`

`Hi , this is my website : website.com`

specially , i want to remove correctly the ( ' website.com ' )

any ideas ? thanks

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: ` Hi , this is my website : ` @AvinashRaj

Comment: Thanks for down vote , but please, just answer the question :)

Comment: Just remove everything after the `:` till the end of the line.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid its just a " Assume " , the actual string is dynamic and could be anything after , before ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below regex and replace the matched strings with an empty string through `preg_replace`

```
(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:my\.)?website\.com
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zI0fR8/5)

[PHP live](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/7wy)

**Update:**

```
\b(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[-\w]+(?:\.[-\w]+)*\.(?:com|in|tk|ir|info)\b
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zI0fR8/8)

Comment: it could be any domain , with any ltd , you just gave me an static answer ,could you change the ?website\.com to something that will find the `mysite.com` , `funny.site.com` or ..

Comment: Exactly , but the domain could contain " - " , its not working with it  @AvinashRaj

Comment: ops , the ltd could be .in or .tk or .ir or .info

Comment: @Avinash Raj you are great, I am studing `regex` from your answers

Comment: That's nice, ask me if you have any doubts in my answer :-)

Comment: @AvinashRaj , how to limit it to only replace if its not email address , i mean , im working with you code now , but i facing email addresses

Comment: give me some examples. Post your input here http://regex101.com/ , then save it and finally post back the link here.

Comment: @AvinashRaj hi this is my website : http://website.com/
and heres my email : info@website.com
contact me.

( i tryng remove website.com or replace it , but when i use the code u gave, and replace website.com , to example.com . info@website.com will change to info@example.com )
i want to keep info@website.com and replace the website url

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, I just modified `Avinash Raj's` answer

```
(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:[a-z]+\.)?[a-z]+\.com
```